# Font Awesome is showing empty square instead of the icon on Chrome only and under an IP only

Tags: font-awesome

i read all other posts related to this problem and:

- no, my client is not using any adblocker or other extensions
- i'm including the css with the absolute URL
- i'm using  instead of

The strange thing is that to me everything works perfect on all computers and all browsers.

My client saw it perfectly until last week but the page hasn't been modified! Now they see the famous empty square instead of the right icons.

What could they have installed that stop it ONLY on chrome/desktop.
Chrome is the latest version, same as mine!

Because if it's a problem that only them will see it's fine, but i'd like to understand if there's a common condition that even other users can have.

**I build up a stupid page: http://sviluppo3.sitotemporaneo.com/test/ciccio.html
they see 3 blank squares in the top left corner.**

Tnx!

Comment: Debug this with your client.. not us. We don't know your client's setup nor how his browser is working. If you can't reproduce the problem for us, we cannot help you find your issue.

Comment: I'm asking if there's a known conflict with something. If someone else had the same problem and how they solved it. You shouldn't waste your time to write useless answer. Tnx

Comment: I didn't write any useless answers. Your client has some problem, which we can't do anything about.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me to today and I manage to fix it.
I had display: block; on the .fa () element, so I removed that and let it be display: inline-block;
inline-block is font-awesome standard to the  element